# Origin of Lua Error

Tags: errors, luatex, lua

If a `lualatex` compilation breaks with/at this terminal output:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))[\directlua]:1: attempt to call a nil value (field 'get_functions_tabl
e').
l.1738   }
```

Does it mean the failing `\directlua` is in `/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex`?

Thing is, that file does *not* contain a `directlua`. OTOH *this* error only started o appear after I got lualatex to read and parse an additional Lua file within my personal document infrastructure -- but I don't see anything suspicious of being related in that additional file either.

Comment: the fragment of log you show, shows the error is _not_ in `pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex`  (the `)` shows that file has been read to the end), but you have not shown which file the error is in.

Answer (score 1):

You provided no example, but given a guessed example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

The relevant part of the terminal output is

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
```

The penultimate `)` shows that `pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex` has been read to the end, so the final `)` shown shows that `pgfkeys.code.tex` has been read to the end, so any line number in an error message at this point refers to the file at the top of the stack of open files, which is `pgfsys.code.tex`, line 1738 of which is the closing `}` of this `\directlua` call

```
  \directlua{
  local lft = lua.get_functions_table()
  lft[\string#lft+1] = function()
      local lhs = token.scan_string()
      local rhs = token.scan_string()
      if lhs < rhs then
          tex.sprint(-2, "-1")
      elseif lhs == rhs then
          tex.sprint(-2, "0")
      else
          tex.sprint(-2, "1")
      end
  end
  token.set_lua("pgfsys@strcmp", \string#lft, "global")
  }
```